# Stack Exchange for Android right facing arrows

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, android-app

I had [made a comment](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&reviewId=Z3A6QU9xcFRPR0VfaG4yWlJRVkNmaDJvd2VaWmNnQVhNQ21qSkJBdjRoam1DTXB0UDljSE5tN0U0UzJGRzRvMGRiX2xXSGNBUWZEZVA3aDhJWXJEV3phOFE) on the Google Play listing for the Stack Exchange app mentioning the right-facing arrows.  One of the developers requested the screenshots of the arrows I was referring to, so here we go:

[image: Right Facing Arrows]

So it's on the profile page; there are right facing arrows for each Stack Exchange site you are a part of.

I know I'm nitpicking but [the guidelines state](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) that right facing arrows are taboo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh that's what you were talking about! I thought you meant the triangles on comments which are a regular android asset. Sadly I think in this case this is going to stay as is, since there are two click areas on those: one for making the card expand and one for going in depth into it.

Also important to note that the guidelines you link are talking about settings pages and line items, where this is more a "card" than a line item.

Comment: Aaaahhh ok, I didnt even realize that there were multiple actions for that card. I'll let it slide my friend :).  Or if I get a stroke of genius I'll suggest some new UI here.